# AngularJS ng-click or ng-submit in directive causes page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a strange behavior in my custom Angular directive that is causing the page to refresh on clicking the "Save Button" which is in a custom directive. For simplicity and debugging, I created the same button behavior in my parent DOM but that doesnt cause the page to refresh. Here is my code:

```
//Main DOM parent.html
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.saveReleases()">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send to Ingestion</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

// Parent controller parent.controller.js

function saveReleases(){
        console.log("Hello");
    }
```

Below is the custom directive code:

```
custom directive: custom-directive.html
<form>
 .
 .
 .
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-submit="vm.saveRelease()">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send to Ingestion</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the directive for the above custom html directive:
    //custom.directive.js

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('app.uploadedReleases').directive('releaseMetadata', releaseMetadata);

function releaseMetadata(){
    var releaseMetadataDirective = {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/uploadedReleases/directive/custom-directive.html',
        scope: {
            selected :'='
        },
        controller: ReleaseMetadataCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
return releaseMetadataDirective;
}

function Album(title, genre){
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;

    this.merge = function(album){
        album.title = this.title;
        album.genre = this.genre;
        return album;
    }
}

ReleaseMetadataCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function ReleaseMetadataCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.saveRelease = saveRelease;
    console.log("scope selected: ")
    console.log($scope.selected);
    vm.formAlbum = new Album($scope.selected.album.data.title, $scope.selected.album.genre);

    console.log("scope vm.formAlbum:")
    console.log (vm.formAlbum);


    function saveRelease(){
        console.log("save in directive");
    }
}
})();
```

The custom directive tag is actually supposed to be called within the parent DOM, which is why I created that custom directive but clicking the SAVE button in the custom directive element when it shows up causes it to reload, but clicking on the SAVE for the parent DOM exactly calls and prints HELLO on the console. The function in the custom directive isn't even called when the button is clicked. Any clues ?

Comment: Try changing that button into an input with the type="submit"

Comment: @Bata I tried both ways. With and without type = submit but no change

Comment: I am talking about the <button> tag.  Change it to <input>.

Comment: @Bata correct me if I am wrong, but it I change it to input, it will behave like an input box and not a button. Also, the parent DOM has it as <button> and has no issues. So not sure how this would help. I still tried though and yes, it behaves like an input box and not a button.

Comment: example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94rL65ue/